# Creating byte array from string vs from file

Tags: arrays, powershell, encryption, encoding, rsa

I am trying to decrypt some text.
I am able to decrypt text from a file, however when I copy the contents of that file and put it directly in a string, it doesn't work because the byte arrays are slightly different.

How can I get a byte array from a string, which is the same byte array as when reading from a file containing that string?

Here is my code:

```
$privateKeyFile = [System.IO.FileInfo]'D:\Avanade\CBA\Scripts\Encryption\Keys\cba.private.xml'
$privateKey = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($($privateKeyFile.FullName)).ReadToEnd() 

$rsaProvider = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsaProvider.FromXmlString($privateKey)

$encryptedData = 'ꨢﻥ睚紫震እ�풽꞊偓䷨頽ױ㻮앚튛堏焞娌젣래核儝쪅元㝂㢚覰齉c㑥㰺ᨅ㵉ァ镮邹꽋荺眢ꢈ쑷絓�ꮹ栊ﾊ垅懻惜䡠덟蓩瘫㙉ਧ騰י聗�၁틽ᮿ싓㈧ハ腰瑦ꊕ媘겻辖庖甏ܫ桑敘옐餈꿎請쌝⢸蒺銟஦ᩅ캼Շ疑ꊽ�䐼ꀑ醾耣咞䏎帾힆纄܏㎡㨇괎ꆠ䵢싐쇢绽굈ữ禘'
$encryptedDataAsByteArray1 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UniCode.GetBytes($encryptedData) #this byte array does NOT work

$FileToDecrypt = [System.IO.FileInfo]'D:\Avanade\CBA\Scripts\Encryption\d.txt.encrypted' #this has the same text as $encryptedData
$encryptedFile = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($($FileToDecrypt.FullName))
$encryptedDataAsByteArray = New-Object System.Byte[] $encryptedFile.Length #This byte array works
$encryptedFile.Read($encryptedDataAsByteArray, 0, $encryptedFile.Length) 
$encryptedFile.Close()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $encryptedDataAsByteArray1.Count; $i++)
{
    if ($encryptedDataAsByteArray1[$i] -ne $encryptedDataAsByteArray[$i])
    {
        Write-Host "Byte $i is not the same"
        Write-Host "$($encryptedDataAsByteArray1[$i]) and $($encryptedDataAsByteArray[$i])"
    }
}

$decryptedDataAsByteArray = $rsaProvider.Decrypt($encryptedDataAsByteArray, $false)

<#
Comparison of the two byte arrays:
Byte 12 is not the same
253 and 47
Byte 13 is not the same
255 and 223
Byte 92 is not the same
253 and 179
Byte 93 is not the same
255 and 223
Byte 132 is not the same
253 and 127
Byte 133 is not the same
255 and 223
Byte 204 is not the same
253 and 67
Byte 205 is not the same
#>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply base 64 encoding over the file, e.g. using a utility such as the `openssl` command line. Then copy this using the clipboard into the string. Finally, simply decode it within the application.

```
openssl base64 -in test.bin
```

results in:

```
VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCB3YXMganVtcGVkIGJ5IHRoZSBzbGVhenkgZG9n
Lg==
```

The problem with just copying it into a string is that you'll get character-encoding issues. The encrypted bytes can have any value, including control characters and other non-printable characters. Those won't copy well.

Here's how to [encode/decode using powershell](http://vstepic.blogspot.nl/2013/02/how-to-convert-string-to-base64-and.html). Note that you don't need to perform the character (UTF-8) encoding/decoding if you are (already) dealing with bytes.

Comment: Thankyou so much!
I ended up using Convert.ToBase64String from .NET which works well.

Comment: Is there any benefit from using openssl over the .NET Convert class?

Comment: Heh, no. I just came across this question because of the encryption tag and I'm currently on Linux. The idea is the same though.